# Unable to override Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract

Tags: magento, overriding

In magento 1.9.2, To remove Telephone number as mandatory field from checkout page I copied the app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php to app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php . Cleared cache and tested. But still the core file is only accessed. How can I get the local file to override?

Comment: You can definitely override core abstract mode by moving it to local code pool. The way you described it, it should work. How do you know that core file is still accessed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow this:

[Checkout Telephone Not Required](https://codepen.io/patrickkahl/post/magento-making-the-telephone-field-not-required-at-checkout)

It is same that you required to do. It specify multiple way.

Answer (score 0):

Well i just Google this "magento remove telephone number field from checkout"

And i got this link on first result [Click here](http://swarminglabs.com/magento-making-the-telephone-field-not-required-at-checkout/)

And because i am posting this in answer i have tried follwoing that link in magento 1.9 and it gives what you want.Just give it a try.